# Implementing PFQueryTableViewController with Cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, parse-platform

Had a little bit of trouble replacing my TableViewController with PFQueryTableViewController, but I got it working with pull to refresh and pagination. However, I can't get the cache to work (at the very bottom of the .m file). Any ideas on what's going on?

The only other change I made here was subclass the image in the cell as PFImage.

ContactsTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "FilterViewController.h"

@interface ContactsTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *titleName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *price;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *imageName;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *venue;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *filter;

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *eventsArray;

-(void)retrieveEvents;
-(void)filterEvents;

@end
```

ContactsTableViewController.m

```
#import "ContactsTableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ContactsTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation ContactsTableViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"eventsList";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
//        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveEvents)];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(filterEvents) name:@"updateParent" object:nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:243/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1];
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.eventsArray count];
}

// Parse Method

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    CustomCellTableViewCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.titleName = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];
    self.price = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventPrice"];
    self.date = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"];
    self.venue = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventVenue"];

    PFFile *imageFile = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventImage"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            customCell.customImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
    }];

    customCell.titleLabel.text = self.titleName;
    customCell.priceLabel.text = self.price;
    customCell.customDateLabel.text = self.date;
    customCell.venueNameLabel.text = self.venue;


    return customCell;
}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEventDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *destinationVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        destinationVC.eventTitle = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];
        destinationVC.eventPrice = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventPrice"];
        destinationVC.eventDate = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"];
        destinationVC.venueName = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventVenue"];
        destinationVC.navigationItem.title = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];

        // Image
        PFFile *imageFile = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventImage"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                destinationVC.eventImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                destinationVC.eventImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
        }];

        // GeoPoint
        destinationVC.geoPoint = [tempDict objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showFilterTable"]){

        FilterViewController *vc = (FilterViewController *)[[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        [vc setDelegate:self];

    }
}

-(void)retrieveEvents
{

    PFQuery *retrieveEvents = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"eventsList"];
    [retrieveEvents setLimit:300];
    [retrieveEvents orderByAscending:@"eventTitle"];
    [retrieveEvents findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.eventsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}


-(void)filterEvents
{
    if ([self.filter isEqualToString:@"All Events"]) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveEvents)];
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"retrieveEvents: %@", self.filter);
    PFQuery *retrieveEvents = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"eventsList"];
    [retrieveEvents whereKey:@"eventType" equalTo:self.filter];
    [retrieveEvents setLimit:300];
    [retrieveEvents orderByAscending:@"eventTitle"];
    [retrieveEvents findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.eventsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.eventsArray);
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}

// Parse Method

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

    return query;
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "can't get it to work"?  What's not working?

Comment: Caching isn't working. I run the app with this code, kill it, put airplane mode on, restart the app, and I don't get anything to load. This is what a tutorial suggested to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you are not using the queryForTable to populate the tableview, you are using your separate query.

This query never gets used in your tableview

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

    return query;
}
```

Instead this one does:

```
-(void)retrieveEvents
{

    PFQuery *retrieveEvents = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"eventsList"];
    [retrieveEvents setLimit:300];
    [retrieveEvents orderByAscending:@"eventTitle"];
    [retrieveEvents findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.eventsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Comment: You're right. Got it working putting the line right above the setLimit method. Thanks guys!

Comment: You are improperly using PFQueryTableViewController if you are not populating your cell data from self objectAtIndexPath: This is where your queryForTable returns it's results.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial I could follow? I only know how to call a method in viewDidLoad to retrieve events. But now it's not retrieving 'objects.' My eventsArray is empty. Was just fine yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

`kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork` means to use both cache and network (first get from cache for quickness, then get from network for up-to-date-ness the next time).  Try instead using `kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork`.

Comment: Wouldn't it get the cached cells first either way? I tried both and it's still not bringing anything up when I reopen the app in airplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may not be perfect. But I believe it should at least head you in the right direction.

```
#import "ContactsTableViewController.h"
#import "CustomCellTableViewCell.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ContactsTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation ContactsTableViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"eventsList";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        //        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(filterEvents) name:@"updateParent" object:nil];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:245/255.0 green:243/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1];
    tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //This reloaded the PFQueryTableView
    [self loadObjects];
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.objects.count;
}

// Parse Method

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    CustomCellTableViewCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject *object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    customCell.titleLabel.text = object[@"eventTitle"];
    customCell.priceLabel.text = object[@"eventPrice"];
    customCell.customDateLabel.text = object[@"eventDate"];
    customCell.venueNameLabel.text = object[@"eventVenue"];
    PFFile *imageFile = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventImage"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            customCell.customImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
    }];
    return customCell;
}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showEventDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *destinationVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
        destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        destinationVC.eventTitle = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];
        destinationVC.eventPrice = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventPrice"];
        destinationVC.eventDate = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventDate"];
        destinationVC.venueName = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventVenue"];
        destinationVC.navigationItem.title = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventTitle"];

        // Image
        PFFile *imageFile = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventImage"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                destinationVC.eventImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                destinationVC.eventImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
        }];

        // GeoPoint
        destinationVC.geoPoint = [tempDict objectForKey:@"GeoPoint"];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showFilterTable"]){

        FilterViewController *vc = (FilterViewController *)[[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];

        [vc setDelegate:self];

    }
}
// Parse Method
-(NSString *)filter
{
    return _filter;
}
-(void)setFilter
{
    _filter = filter;
    [self loadObjects];
}
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    if (self.filter && ![self.filter isEqualToString:@"All Events"]) [query whereKey:@"eventTitle" equalTo:self.filter];
    [query setLimit:300];
    [query orderByAscending:@"eventTitle"];
    return query;
}
@end
```